# how to run a selenium-server-standalone?

Tags: java, selenium, jar, server

I'm trying to run selenium server, and get errors:

```
rond-macpro:selenium eladb$  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -r selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
Unrecognized option: -r
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

and  without -r (what is it anyway?)

```
rond-macpro:selenium eladb$  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver  selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
```

how should I start the server?

how do I set a non-default port to listen to?

These two posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883450/selenium-invalid-already-running-error-when-starting-server) [2](https://deors.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/selenium-webdriver-grid-1/) - contradicts regarding the syntax. I think.

Comment: one question: why do you need to specify the chrome driver here ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
java -jar seleniumjar.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver
```

If you want to specifiy the port do

```
java -jar seleniumjar.version.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -port 4545
```

As of 3.8.1, specifying the driver is no longer necessary:

```
java -jar seleniumjar.jar
```

Comment: how come your cmd doesn't include main class path?

Comment: @EladBenda I am sorry. Please clarify more

Comment: for java in general, if the jar includes only one main class, we don't have to write its name in the `java -jar cmd`?

Comment: Ooh gotcha. This is how `seleniumHQ` actually suggest to run this. Never wanted to dig into how it works internally

Comment: Just FYI if order of args in answer crashes, try to switch the order: driver first, then jar. Such order solved it for me as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032960/unknown-option-dwebdriver-chrome-driver-when-running-selenium-server-standalon

Comment: Does not work for standalone driver 3.4, the option "webdriver.chrome.driver" is not known.

Comment: @rocksportrocker I need to test that. That should not break though

Comment: how can i use GhostDriver (PhantomJS) instead of ChromeDriver?

Comment: @johnlowvale you would need to register the node after the server is up. But please note ghost driver and PhantomJs is no longer being maintained at this time.

*** phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 ***

Answer (score 15):

**Running Standalone [Selenium Server](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html):**

*Form [Jar Source](https://github.com/Yash-777/SeleniumSource) **Main-Class** is* `org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher`

As per **`GridRole`** class - Selenium server can run in one of the following roles:

> 1. **`NOT_GRID`** *[If -role option is omitted the server runs standalone not being a part of a grid]*>
> 2. **`HUB`** *[as a hub of a Selenium grid]*
> 3. **`NODE`** *[as a node of a Selenium grid]*

```
D:\> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-*.jar -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4444
```

---

**NOT GRID**

- **`RC`**[`(Selenium interface)`](https://github.com/Yash-777/SeleniumSource/blob/master/java/client/src/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.java)**`- IP:Port/selenium-server`**:

***[Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) Remote Control ([RC](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#using-the-java-client-driver)) requires server to be started before executing the test scripts.*** RC server injects **Selenium core (JavaScript)** into the browser. The core (daemon process) receives commands from the server by your test scripts and executes them in a browser then results to your program. But cannot handle moving mouse cursors  & mobile execution.

Java Client Driver: 
*Client-Configures your browser to use the Selenium Server as an HTTP proxy and passes browser commands to server through `"/selenium-server/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=1234"`, clients may send Driver **Command requests** to selenium server over HTTP as follows:*

*Code & Requests: RC Server continuously runs. we create a daemon and from that communicate with the browser.*

```
Selenium daemon = new DefaultSelenium("172.16.20.156", 4464, "*firefox", "https://www.google.co.in/");
daemon.start(); -- daemon.stop(); (OR)
setUp("http://www.google.com/", "*firefox", 4454); selenium.windowMaximize();

GET:http://localhost:4454/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=open&1=https://www.google.co.in/&sessionId=9b1a232d9478497892e09cfc93cf665a
```

- **`RC`**([`WebDriver`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#backing-webdriver-with-selenium)`interface)`**`- IP:Port/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`**:

*[RWD](https://github.com/Yash-777/SeleniumSource/wiki/RemoteWebDriver) Code & [Requests](https://advancedrestclient.com/)*:

```
WebDriver nativeDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4454/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

Requests:
http://127.0.0.1:4454/wd/hub/session
    /123...[SESSIONID]
        /url
        { "url" : "http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/login" }


        /execute
        { "script" : "document.querySelectorAll( arguments[0] )[0].click();", "args" : ['input.btn'] }
```

---

**[Grid](https://github.com/Yash-777/SeleniumSource/wiki/Grid2)**: [ `- IP:Port/grid/console`]

**HUB** *`Grid HUB Running as a standalone server:` Hub is a central point which distributing tests on several node-machines, which are registered to it for parallel execution.*

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4454 -role hub -log "D:\\HUB_Log.txt"
```

**NODE** *[RC] has to post a request to HUB in order to register with it, by this URL - `IP:Port//grid/register`.*

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4458 -role node 
-hub http://127.0.0.1:4454/grid/register -hubHost 127.0.0.1 -hubPort 4454 
-browser browserName=firefox,version=24.0, maxinstance=1,platform=WINDOWS7 
-browser  browserName=chrome,version=53.0,platform=WINDOWS 
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\\Drivers\\chromedrivers\\2.24\\chromedriver.exe
```

*`Running as a grid node:` browser Instance INFO: browserName=chrome, version=53.0, maxinstance=1, platform=WINDOWS Command Line parameters with [System Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) values -Dproperty=value -D[chrome](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)=[driverAddress](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/) (If value is a string that contains spaces, you must enclose the string in double quotes)*

Node registration with a **JSON configuration file [`registerNode.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320490/5081877)**.

```java
D:\SeleniumJar_Source>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node 
-hub http://127.0.0.1:4454/grid/register 
-nodeConfig registerNode.json 
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\\Drivers\\chromedrivers\\2.24\\chromedriver.exe" 
-Dwebdriver.ie.driver="D:\\Drivers\\IEDrivers\\iedriver64\\IEDriverServer.exe" 
-Dwebdriver.firefox.logfile="D:\\FirefoxInstance.txt" 
-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile="D:\\ChromeInstance.txt" 
-Dwebdriver.ie.logfile="D:\\IEInstance.txt"
```

---

**WebDriver** doesn't require any server start before start execution. You can see that [WebDriver](https://github.com/Yash-777/SeleniumSource/wiki/Getting-Started) acts just as a normal Java library does: it's entirely self-contained, and you don't need to remember to start any additional processes or run any installers before using it.

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

---

[image: Selenium Server]

@see

- [Selenium using Java: Start Hub Server and register Nodes with Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320490/5081877)
- [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/Yash-777/SeleniumDriverAutomation/wiki/Selenium)

Answer (score 6):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -port port_no
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add more webdrivers to @Saifur answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28854250/4587961

```
java   -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./IEDriverServer32.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver.exe -jar selenium.jar -port 4545
```

Note, for IE you run 32 bit version of the driver. And it works. I created a bat file and put it inside of the selenium folder where I also put drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Selenium >= 4.6 use

```
java -jar selenium-server-<version>.jar standalone
```

See this page for further instructions

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/getting_started/

Answer (score 0):

One should first specify the driver part then the selenium jar :

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

This worked for Ubuntu 18.04