# Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver when running selenium server standalone on Mac

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to manually run `selenium server standalone` on MAC and then run my tests with intern-runner in Chrome browser. As I've been advised on intern User Guide:

> "To use `ChromeDriver` and `IEDriver` with a Selenium server, the driver executable must either be placed somewhere in the environment PATH, or their locations must be given explicitly to the Selenium server using the `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver (ChromeDriver)` and `-Dwebdriver.ie.driver (IEDriver)` flags upon starting the Selenium server."

I started the Selenium server and put path to chrome driver on my machine, but got error:

["Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYA7I.png)

any idea on why `seleinum` unable to recognize the options?

Is there any  other solution on how to run `chrome webdriver/IE webDriver` from command line with selenium standalone server?

Where the driver executable could be placed in the environment PATH on MAC?

I was able to run chrome driver separately with out any issues using:

```
./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver --port=4444 --url-base=wd/hub
```

Answer (score 10):

For selenium3 you need to use Dwebdriver.chrome.driver option first.

`java -Dwebdrive.chrome.driver=path_to_chrome_driver -jar selenium_server_file`

To avoid any path issues better download both files in the same directory and run from there.

Example:

`java -Dwebdrive.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar`

Also have Chrome browser installed.

> Is drive instead of driver

Comment: Thank you @lauda. Selenium Server is up and running now.

Comment: If `Dwebdrive` does not working you an try with `Dwebdriver`