# Selenium using Java: Start Hub Server and register Nodes with Hub

Tags: java, selenium, remote-server, selenium3

I am new to the selenium and I have been trying to start Selenium Hub and adding the node to the Hub using java. I have started it using command prompt but I want it to happen on its own. I am able to start the Hub but have no Idea how to add the Node.

Following is my code to start the Hub:

```
import org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.GridHubConfiguration;
import org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.GridNodeConfiguration;
import org.openqa.grid.web.Hub;

public class StartHub {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GridHubConfiguration configHub = new GridHubConfiguration();
        configHub.host = "localhost";
        configHub.port = 8060;

        //GridNodeConfiguration configNode = new GridNodeConfiguration();
        //configNode.host = configHub.host;
        //configNode.port = 5300;

        Hub hub = new Hub(configHub);
        //configNode.getHubHost();
        hub.start();

        //System.out.println(configNode.getRemoteHost());

        //hub.stop();
    }

}
```

How to add a Node going forward ?

Comment: You've already successfully started the node from the command line manually? In that case just copy the command you used there, and execute the same command from java,  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");

Comment: Yeah @PatMeeker thats a good option but thats not I want. The above command is requires a .bat/.sh/.exe file dependency which I want to remove.

Comment: Is that because you don't want the manual step of putting the file on the node machine first? Can you just include the dependency in your Java project instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Selenium-Grid Server Version 2.x.x configuration.

> Their Packages list
>
> ```
> « org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.GridHubConfiguration;
> « org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;
> ```

**HUB** [`Grid HUB Running as a standalone server`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640250/5081877): *Hub is a central point which distributing tests on several node-machines, which are registered to it for parallel execution.*

*Use GRID HUB Server:*

- *To distribute your tests over multiple machines or virtual machines (VMs).*
- *You want to connect to a remote machine that has a particular browser version that is not on your current machine.*

> Start HUB Server
>
> - [loadFromCommandLine(String[] args)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640250/5081877) - Go through my previous post.
> - loadFromJSON(String resource) - resource `default/DefaultHub.json` for instance

```java
public class Grid_HUBServer {

    public static String HUBIP = GRIDINFO.HOSTIP.toString();
    public static Integer HUBPORT = 4444;
    static String separator = "\n------------------------\n";

    public static void hubServer() {
        try {
            GridHubConfiguration gridHubConfig = new GridHubConfiguration();
            gridHubConfig.setHost( HUBIP );
            gridHubConfig.setPort( HUBPORT );
            gridHubConfig.setNewSessionWaitTimeout( 50000 );
            File JOSNFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/gridHub.json" );
            gridHubConfig.loadFromJSON( JOSNFile.toString() );


            Hub hub = new Hub(gridHubConfig);
            hub.start();

            System.out.println("Nodes should register to " + hub.getRegistrationURL());
            System.out.format("%s Running as a grid hub: %s\n" +
                    "Console URL : %s/grid/console \n", separator,separator,hub.getUrl());

            System.out.println("Please Enter to stop service.");
            System.in.read();
            System.in.read();

            hub.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hubServer();
    }
}
```

**NODE [RC]** *has to post a request to HUB in order to register with it, by this URL - `IP:Port//grid/register`.*

```java
public class Grid_NODEServer extends Grid_HUBServer {
    static Integer NODEPORT = 5555;
    static String PROXYCLASS = "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy";

    public static void nodeServer() {
        try {
            System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, CHROME_DRIVER_EXE );
            System.setProperty(InternetExplorerDriverService.IE_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, IE_DRIVER_EXE);


            RegistrationRequest request = new RegistrationRequest();
            request.setRole( GridRole.NODE );
            File JOSNFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/registerNode.json" );
            request.loadFromJSON( JOSNFile.toString() );

            Map<String, Object> configuration = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            URL remoteURL = new URL(String.format("http://%s:%d", HUBIP, HUBPORT) );
            System.out.println("Remote URL : "+remoteURL);
            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.AUTO_REGISTER, true);
            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.HUB_HOST, HUBIP);
            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.HUB_PORT, HUBPORT);
            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.REMOTE_HOST, remoteURL);

            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.PORT, NODEPORT);

            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.PROXY_CLASS, PROXYCLASS);
            configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.MAX_SESSION, 1);
            //configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.CLEAN_UP_CYCLE, 2000);
            //configuration.put(RegistrationRequest.MAX_INSTANCES, 1);

            request.setConfiguration( configuration );
            GridNodeServer node = new SeleniumServer( request.getConfiguration() );

            SelfRegisteringRemote remote = new SelfRegisteringRemote( request );
            remote.setRemoteServer( node );
            remote.startRemoteServer();
            System.out.format("Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub " +
                    "%s Running as a grid node: %s ", separator,separator);
            remote.startRegistrationProcess();

            System.out.println("Please Enter to stop service.");
            System.in.read();
            System.in.read();

            remote.stopRemoteServer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nodeServer();
    }
}
```

[Selenium-Grid](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) - JSON Configuration Files for HUB & NODE are [`gridHub.json`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json), [`registerNode.json`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json) to instantiate.

```json
{
  "host": null,
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,

  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "browserTimeout": 1800000,
  "maxSession": 5,
  "jettyMaxThreads":-1
}
```

```json
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "version": "39.0",
          "firefox_binary": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "version": "54.0",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "version": "11",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "role": "node",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5555,

    "maxSession": 5,
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "registerCycle": 10000,
    "nodeTimeout":120,
    "nodePolling":2000,

    "register": true,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

---

### Selenium-Grid Server Version [3.x.x (>= beta4) configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes-by-json).

> Their packages list - (`org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server`)
>
> ```
> « org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.GridHubConfiguration;
> « org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer;
> « org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.GridNodeConfiguration;
> ```

```Java
//  HUB Configuration - org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.GridHubConfiguration
GridHubConfiguration gridHubConfig = new GridHubConfiguration();
gridHubConfig.host = HUBIP;
gridHubConfig.port = HUBPORT;
gridHubConfig.newSessionWaitTimeout = 50000;
File JOSNFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/gridHub.json" );
gridHubConfig.loadFromJSON( JOSNFile.toString() );

Hub hub = new Hub(gridHubConfig);
hub.start();

// NODE Configuration - org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer
GridNodeConfiguration configuration = new GridNodeConfiguration();

File JOSNFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/registerNode2.json" );
configuration.loadFromJSON( JOSNFile.toString() );
configuration.role = GridRole.NODE.name();

URL remoteURL = new URL(String.format("http://%s:%d", HUBIP, HUBPORT) );
System.out.println("Remote URL : "+remoteURL);
RegistrationRequest request = new RegistrationRequest( configuration );

GridNodeServer node = new SeleniumServer( request.getConfiguration() );

SelfRegisteringRemote remote = new SelfRegisteringRemote( request );
remote.setRemoteServer( node );
remote.startRemoteServer();
remote.startRegistrationProcess();
```

Use different JSON format to overcome the Exception - `org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridConfigurationException: Error with the JSON of the config : Deprecated -nodeConfig file encountered.`

[registerNode2.json](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json)

```json
{
    "capabilities": [ ... ],

    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "role": "node",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5555,

    "maxSession": 5,
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "nodePolling": 5000,
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
    "downPollingLimit": 2,
    "debug": false,

    "register": true,
    "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
    "servlets" : [],
    "withoutServlets": [],
    "custom": {}
}
```