# Starting selenium standalone server and geckodriver on Windows OS

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-server

I have downloaded the selenium-standalone-server.jar and the geckodriver.exe for my windows OS.

In order to start the server with geckodriver i have seen this command in Linux OS.

```
$ java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar
```

How do i do this on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

To start the *Selenium Server* you don't need to pass *GeckoDriver* as a parameter and to start the *Selenium Server* in default configuration you can use the following line of command on *Windows OS* :

```
>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
```

Console Output :

```
C:\path\to>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
16:05:41.383 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'
16:05:41.384 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-04-24 16:05:41.539:INFO::main: Logging initialized @523ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
16:05:42.071 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Welcome to Selenium for Workgroups....
16:05:42.071 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to pass the Gecko parameter though?

Comment: IMO, We shouldn't configure the _Selenium Server_  or the _Selenium Grid Hub_ to be restricted only to a single _WebDriver_ variant. Having said that I am yet to work with _Selenium Server_ but with _Selenium Grid Hub_ it is a absolute **No**. Instead the _Selenium Server clients_ or _Selenium Grid Nodes_ must be configured with the _WebDriver_ variant.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-XX.XX.jar -port port_no
```

Hope this'll help you !

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to pass the Gecko parameter though?

Comment: As of 3.8.1, specifying the driver is no longer necessary: for more reference you can follow this SO post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853634/how-to-run-a-selenium-server-standalone?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=pathToGeckoDriver selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
```

Ex : pathToGeckoDriver=C:\Users\Selenium\geckodriver.exe